# ChartJS pie chart with simple parsing options doesn't render, only works when set as bar/line chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this chart that works normally

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

const cfg = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: receivedData,
            label:"testSet"
        }]
    },
    options: {
        parsing: {
            yAxisKey: 'COUNT',
            xAxisKey: 'MODEL'
        }
    }
    };

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, cfg);
```

`receivedData` contains objects with the following properties

```
    {MODEL:"model name", COUNT:10}
```

the problem is if i try to change the chart's type to **pie** or **doughnut**, then the chart won't render, **bar** and **line** works normally though.

is this some sort of bug or am i doing something wrong?

i'm using chart.js's latest version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you cant use object notation for doughnut/pie charts, there is an enchancement issue open currently in their repo for this: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/9440

So you will need to transform your object to the normal labels and data array first if you want to show your data as a pie/doughnut chart

Comment: This issue is marked as fixed, however the main documentation of the latest version (3.9.1) still asks for number array, and parsing does not seem to work.

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/general/data-structures.html#object-using-custom-properties